# In Android, use the phone default Dialer to launch an Activity?

Tags: java, android

In my app, the user creates a 4 digit code that is stored as a Shared Preference. The user will make a call, and with the phone call in progress (after the call has been answered), and my app running in the background, is it possible to type that 4 digit code into the default `Dialer` on the phone and have that dialed-in code launch an intent that would launch an Activity in my app? If this is possible can anyone give me some suggestions as to how to achieve this?